# ncftp only download folders, but not files inside folders

Tags: ftp

I am trying to download all files from a remote ftp server using ncftp, but I found that using the suggested "-R" option only allows me to download all the folders, but not any files inside the folders. The full command is

```
ncftp> get -R /pub
```

I also tried ncftpget

```
$ ncftpget -R -T -v ftp.example.com . /pub
$ ncftpget -R ftp.example.com . /pub
```

both of them only download the /pub folder and subfolders, but not any files! 
What can I do to download files? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use "lftp" instead of ncftp. 
The "-R" option of ncftp only works if the remote server is Unix. Otherwise, it does not work.

The command to download the remote server using lftp is

```
lftp -e 'mirror [remote dir] [local dir]' [remote server]
```

for example, if you want to fetch the entire directory from
ftp.example.com/pub/ to your local directory /home/tom, use the following command

```
lftp -e 'mirror /pub /home/tom/' ftp.example.com
```